# Apple Push Notification Bundle Name

Tags: notifications, push, alert, apple-push-notifications

By default the title of an push notification alert will be the bundle name which we provide in the info plist file.

I'm having a short name representation as bundle name in info plist file which we used as a application name in springboard. But i want a different name as title in the alert (push notification alert) and not the short name which i mentioned in the info list file.

Whether it is possible to change the title of the push alert by any means of settings (from app side) or any changes in provider side?

Regards,
Balaji R.

Answer (score 1):

Not possible. Would be documented under http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/ApplePushService/ApplePushService.html