# Apple Push Notification Service - change title of notification message

Tags: ios, json, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I have APNS messages working well.  However I'd like to change the title of the messages that are sent.  Currently the title is always the name of my app.  I see that notifications for the native iOS 'Mail' app have the 'From' address as the title of the message and also have the email subject showing in bold as a sub-heading to the notification.  I'd like to reproduce this for my app's notifications but can't see how to do this.  The JSON payload just seems to have a key for "alert" with no mention of a 'title' key.  Is it possible to achieve what I want?

Comment: I think that you can't do that. In the native mail app is done because it was made by Apple, and as you said it.. it's native.

Comment: --> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6210196/apple-push-notification-bundle-name

Comment: the answer is not possible :) sorry

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I just stumbled over this old question and just wanted to add, that specifying a title and body for the notification is now possible (since iOS 8, I think).

Your push payload needs to look like this:

```
{
  "aps": {
    "alert": {
        "title": "New Message from Boss",
        "body": "Can you complete the new feature until tomorrow, please?!"
    }
  }
}
```

You find the detailed specs in Apple's [Local and Remove Notification Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/PayloadKeyReference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH17-SW5).

Answer (score 5):

Not possible to change the title of APNS messages.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible!

The ApnsPHP_Message class in Message.php is needed to modify a bit:

// new var for title

```
protected $_titleText;
```

// creating setter&getter method for title

```
public function setTitleText($sText)
{
    $this->_titleText = $sText;
}

public function getTitleText()
{
    return $this->_titleText;
}
```

// modify _getPayload method

```
protected function _getPayload()
{
    $aPayload[self::APPLE_RESERVED_NAMESPACE] = array();

    if (isset($this->_sText)) {

        if(isset($this->_titleText)){
            $aPayload[self::APPLE_RESERVED_NAMESPACE]['alert']['title'] = (string)$this->_titleText;
            $aPayload[self::APPLE_RESERVED_NAMESPACE]['alert']['body'] = (string)$this->_sText; 
        }else{
            $aPayload[self::APPLE_RESERVED_NAMESPACE]['alert'] = (string)$this->_sText;
        }

    }
    if (isset($this->_nBadge) && $this->_nBadge > 0) {
        $aPayload[self::APPLE_RESERVED_NAMESPACE]['badge'] = (int)$this->_nBadge;
    }
    if (isset($this->_sSound)) {
        $aPayload[self::APPLE_RESERVED_NAMESPACE]['sound'] = (string)$this->_sSound;
    }

    if (is_array($this->_aCustomProperties)) {
        foreach($this->_aCustomProperties as $sPropertyName => $mPropertyValue) {
            $aPayload[$sPropertyName] = $mPropertyValue;
        }
    }

    return $aPayload;
}
```

And with this modification you can set push message title:

```
$message->setTitleText("This is title");
```